# confirmation for the use of store word and load word

Tags: assembly

Is the following code correctly translated into assembly language?
c[i]= a[i]+b[i]; assuming i in `$s0`, a in `$s1`, b in `$s2`, c in `$s3`.

Solution:

```
sll $t0, $s0, 2      #i*4
add $t0, $s1, $t0    #a[i]
lw $t0, 0($t0)

sll $t1, $s0, 2      #i*4
add $t1, $s2, $t1    #b[i]
lw  $t1, 0($t1)
add $t2, $t0, $t1    #a[i]+b[i]

sll $t3, $s0, 2      #i*4
add $t3, $s2, $t3    #c[i]
lw  $t3, 0($t3)      

sw $t2, 0($t3)      # store a[i]+b[i] into c[i]
```

Please check this out and confirm it. I have recently started learning Assembly language. This code might be simple for you, I request you to help me out.

Comment: Have you tried assembling it and then tracing it in a debugger to verify operation?  What precisely isn't working properly?

Comment: What are the types of `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: It seems you did `*c[i]= a[i]+b[i];` instead of `c[i]= a[i]+b[i];`